# BackgroundWorker is currently busy (даже если IsBusy==false)

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, многопоточность

Есть два потока BackgroundWorker
Из одного из них вызываю другой

```
BackgroundWorker workerOne;  
BackgroundWorker workerSecond;

void workerOne_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    var currentWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    ListItemBase item;
    while (!e.Cancel && !currentWorker.CancellationPending 
          && stackAllItems.Count > 0 && (item = stackAllItems.Pop()) != null)
    {
        if (item.thumbnailNotExist)
            continue;

        bool useSecond = GetThumbnail();

        if (useSecond && !e.Cancel && !currentWorker.CancellationPending)
            StartSecond(item);
    }
}

void StartSecond(ListItemBase item)
{
    bool isStart = false;
    lock (cacheItemsStack)
    {
        if (cacheItemsStack.Count == 0 || cacheItemsStack.Peek() != item)
        {
            cacheItemsStack.Push(item);
            isStart = true;
        }
    }
    if (isStart && !workerSecond.IsBusy)//false,но следующая строка выдает ошибку
        workerSecond.RunWorkerAsync();//Exception:BackgroundWorker is currently busy
}
```

Может стоит создавать workerSecond с ключевым словом volatile?
Но как то не уверен, что в этом случае это будет верным решением.

А возможно проблемы и нет - сейчас у меня включена обработка всех exception в студии.

P.S. Добавил больше кода

Comment: Напишите больше кода. Есть хороший шанс, что у вас банальный race condition.

Попробуйте соорудить **минимальный** пример, воспроизводящий проблему (не копипастьте _весь_ код).

Comment: Обновил код.
Да кстати возможны ситуации, что оба потока пытаются обратиться к одному item. 
Важно это или нет, но workerSecond при тестировании работает вхолостую - по некоторым причинам вызываемый им метод нельзя протестить из студии.